# Origen de la expresión "limpio como una patena"

Tags: expresiones

La expresión *estar limpio como una patena* significa, [según el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S8SeBXM), que algo está "muy limpio". Sin embargo, nunca me había parado a pensar qué era una patena en realidad, y descubro estas dos acepciones:

> 1. f. En el rito católico, bandeja pequeña, generalmente dorada, donde se deposita la hostia durante la celebración eucarística.
> 2. f. Lámina o medalla grande que se usaba como alhaja o adorno.

Como origen de la expresión veo más plausible la primera, dado que un platito que va a servir para que el cura reparta hostias debe estar sin duda limpio. En todo caso, si algo he aprendido es a dudar de todo, así que pregunto:

- ¿A cuál de las dos acepciones de *patena* (ya presentes en el *Covarrubias* de 1611) se refiere la expresión?
- ¿Cuál fue el origen de la expresión *limpio como una patena*? ¿Se conoce la época y el lugar donde se originó?

Este es el caso más antiguo que encuentro en el CORDE:

> *Yo te aseguro, discípulo, que después de la que han hecho ante los muros de Arlanza, se creerán facultados para dejar más limpio que una patena al primer pasajero que caiga en sus rampantes garras.*
>
> Ramón López Soler, "Los bandos de Castilla o El caballero del cisne", 1830 (España).

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo con [esta página de una empresa de limpieza española](https://topcleanbaleares.com/curiosidades-por-que-se-dice-mas-limpio-que-una-patena/), la expresión proviene de la primera acepción de "patena" (lo que tiene sentido pues, si se considera el valor de la hostia consagrada para el liturgia católica, nada debería estar más limpio que el platillo que la sostiene):

> Hasta ahora os hemos dado muchos consejos de limpieza, hoy vamos a cambiar de tema y vamos a hablaros sobre una de las curiosidades de este sector. Más concretamente, vamos a hacer mención a la expresión ‘limpio como una patena’.
>
> Lo primero que haremos será definir qué es la patena. Este objeto es el recipiente en el que se deposita la hostia durante la misa antes de ser consumida. Normalmente es un platillo que suele ser de oro u otro metal precioso que debe estar reluciente y muy limpio. **El hecho de que allí se depositen las obleas, que después se dan para comulgar, hace que se tenga una especial atención a la hora de limpiarlo**.
>
> Por eso, utilizamos esa expresión en nuestro idioma, y cuando algún objeto brilla especialmente se dice que lo hemos dejado reluciente y más limpio que la patena.

[Aquí](https://www.facebook.com/spanishschoolmadrid/posts/1855399708034053/), otra referencia en el mismo sentido:

> Luis Vives Escuela de Español
> 15 de febrero de 2017 ·
> "Limpio como una patena"
>
> Cuando decimos que algo “está más limpio que una patena” nos referimos a que está reluciente, impoluto… que es casi imposible que esté más limpio de lo que ya está.
>
> **El origen de esta expresión lo encontramos en los platos o discos casi planos y de pequeño tamaño donde se dejan las hostias consagradas durante la misa después de partirlas.**
>
> Este recipiente resalta entre todos los demás por su brillo porque suelen estar elaborados con algún metal precioso, dando una impresión de gran limpieza, de ahí la expresión que hoy nos acompaña.